# Aspect ratio inside outer element

Tags: html, css

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid blueviolet;
  width: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cinema-hall-seats {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cinema-hall-seats">
  <div class="outer" *ngFor="let place of hallPlace; let i = index">
    <div [hidden]="spot % 5 === 0" class="inner" *ngFor="let spot of place; let j = index">
      <span>{{spot}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try set width same as hight try add to .inner class padding-top: 5% but it does't work. My question is how to set same width and hight inner div element?

Comment: Please can you clarify what the end goal is - are you wanting .inside to be a square that hjas 5% the width of outer?

Comment: Also why does padding-top 5% not work - it makes a square, the only problem is you have a span inside it and the makes it taller than the square because the padding pushes the span down

Comment: @Pete I have two dimensional array for example [5][20] i have 5 wrapper div name(outer) and inside each div i have twenty div that have same width 100%:20 = 5% => i set that width, and now i want that set also same height as width for inner element

Comment: ok use padding-top:5% (or equal to the width), then position the span absolutely - may need to add relative to inner

Comment: @Pete, thanks it's work

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped :)